# Forcing output in standard mathematical notation in PHP

Tags: php

When i do follow following operation `echo 456/100000000`  i get my output in scientific notation

> 4.56E-6

Is it possible to force the output in standard notation, i.e as `0.00000456`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: This traffic routing answer should have been a comment since it doesn't bother to implement the resolving technique.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/352329)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

`$std =` [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)`( "%.8f", 456/100000000 );`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf("%01.8f",456/100000000);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.