# How to display/avoid the epsilon value in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing output in standard mathematical notation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581583/forcing-output-in-standard-mathematical-notation-in-php)

```
Output displayed: 2e+008
```

How to avoid displaying the epsilon value in php?

```
Output needed: 200000000
```

mysql table

```
   amount   float
```

if i enter 200000000 in input box it stores 2e+008 in mysql and just fetch the value through jquery using this code

```
$amount=$("[id=amountfee]").val();

<?php echo $amount ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add some code - ie how the number is created ? how you currently output the number ?

Comment: added @ManseUK the problem is in mysql table and displaying it

Comment: the problem is not in your mysql table. How it is *stored* isnt important here. your problem is *displaying* it.

Comment: Why have your removed the PHP tag ? how does it get from my SQL to the browser ?

Comment: @Gordon ok - i was expecting the OP to add some code on how it got from MySQL to the browser ...

Comment: Just write
echo number_format($amount, 8);

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `number_format()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

use DECIMAL or DOUBLE as data type instead of float. This will also help you to avoid problems you might have on float.